# Repeated notifications for the same edit

Tags: bug

I've been getting notifications for an edit made almost a month ago multiple times, even after clicking it to mark it as seen.  I currently have three of the same notification

[image: If he keeps adding 51 characters, why isn't it getting any bigger?]

Bug?

Comment: clear cache maybe =/

Comment: Cleared.  Now we wait and see if it comes back...